# MySQL upper case table, schema name

Tags: mysql

Environment: Windows 7 64 bit. MySQL version  5.7.18.

I need to create a schema with name `RQATAuto`. It is created with name `rqatauto`.

I used these articles:
[Mysql table name not working in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795947/mysql-table-name-not-working-in-uppercase) ,

[change table name to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928390/change-table-name-to-upper-case) , but neither helped.

What I tried.

1) I noticed I did not have a file `my.cnf`. It's location: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` I created it, and I put a line:

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

When I start MySQL server, I get error.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u root -p
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'lower_case_table_names=2'

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>
```

2) I tried to start MySQL server without `my.cnf` file.

```
mysql> SET lower_case_table_names=2;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'lower_case_table_names' is a read only variable
mysql>
```

I also removed `my.cnf` and created a file `my.ini`

```
# The MySQL server [mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=2

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u root -p
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini at line 2!
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

3) I tried to use MySQL Workbench, it did not allow to use uppercase characters in schema name.

---

### Update

I found file `my.ini` in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` thanks to @Mihai. This is my file

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guildlines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

# pipe
# socket=0.0
port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep

default-character-set=utf8


# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
# server_type=3
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=2
# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking

# enable-named-pipe

# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/"

# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
character-set-server=utf8

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# Enable Windows Authentication
# plugin-load=authentication_windows.dll

# General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="KHOYA01W7.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="KHOYA01W7-slow.log"
long_query_time=10

# Binary Logging.
# log-bin

# Error Logging.
log-error="KHOYA01W7.err"

# Server Id.
server-id=1

# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=151

# Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them
# without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query
# cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your
# have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the
# "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value
# is high enough for your load.
# Note: In case your tables change very often or if your queries are
# textually different every time, the query cache may result in a
# slowdown instead of a performance improvement.
query_cache_size=0

# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_open_cache=2000

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=190M

# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=10

#*** MyISAM Specific options
# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

# If the temporary file used for fast index creation would be bigger
# than using the key cache by the amount specified here, then prefer the
# key cache method.  This is mainly used to force long character keys in
# large tables to use the slower key cache method to create the index.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=370M

# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=8M

# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

#*** INNODB Specific options ***
# innodb_data_home_dir=0.0

# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
# skip-innodb

# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M

# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=48M

# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=17

# The increment size (in MB) for extending the size of an auto-extend InnoDB system tablespace file when it becomes full.
innodb_autoextend_increment=64

# The number of regions that the InnoDB buffer pool is divided into.
# For systems with buffer pools in the multi-gigabyte range, dividing the buffer pool into separate instances can improve concurrency,
# by reducing contention as different threads read and write to cached pages.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

# Determines the number of threads that can enter InnoDB concurrently.
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

# Specifies how long in milliseconds (ms) a block inserted into the old sublist must stay there after its first access before
# it can be moved to the new sublist.
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

# It specifies the maximum number of .ibd files that MySQL can keep open at one time. The minimum value is 10.
innodb_open_files=300

# When this variable is enabled, InnoDB updates statistics during metadata statements.
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

# When innodb_file_per_table is enabled (the default in 5.6.6 and higher), InnoDB stores the data and indexes for each newly created table
# in a separate .ibd file, rather than in the system tablespace.
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Use the following list of values: 0 for crc32, 1 for strict_crc32, 2 for innodb, 3 for strict_innodb, 4 for none, 5 for strict_none.
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

# The number of outstanding connection requests MySQL can have.
# This option is useful when the main MySQL thread gets many connection requests in a very short time.
# It then takes some time (although very little) for the main thread to check the connection and start a new thread.
# The back_log value indicates how many requests can be stacked during this short time before MySQL momentarily
# stops answering new requests.
# You need to increase this only if you expect a large number of connections in a short period of time.
back_log=80

# If this is set to a nonzero value, all tables are closed every flush_time seconds to free up resources and
# synchronize unflushed data to disk.
# This option is best used only on systems with minimal resources.
flush_time=0

# The minimum size of the buffer that is used for plain index scans, range index scans, and joins that do not use
# indexes and thus perform full table scans.
join_buffer_size=256K

# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=4M

# If more than this many successive connection requests from a host are interrupted without a successful connection,
# the server blocks that host from performing further connections.
max_connect_errors=100

# Changes the number of file descriptors available to mysqld.
# You should try increasing the value of this option if mysqld gives you the error "Too many open files".
open_files_limit=4161

# Set the query cache type. 0 for OFF, 1 for ON and 2 for DEMAND.
query_cache_type=0

# If you see many sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output, you can consider increasing the
# sort_buffer_size value to speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with query optimization
# or improved indexing.
sort_buffer_size=256K

# The number of table definitions (from .frm files) that can be stored in the definition cache.
# If you use a large number of tables, you can create a large table definition cache to speed up opening of tables.
# The table definition cache takes less space and does not use file descriptors, unlike the normal table cache.
# The minimum and default values are both 400.
table_definition_cache=1400

# Specify the maximum size of a row-based binary log event, in bytes.
# Rows are grouped into events smaller than this size if possible. The value should be a multiple of 256.
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its master.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_master_info events.
sync_master_info=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, the MySQL server synchronizes its relay log to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log writes to the relay log.
sync_relay_log=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its relay-log.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log_info transactions.
sync_relay_log_info=10000

# Indicates how is the InnoDB Cluster configured as (Classic, Sandbox, Master or Slave).
# innodbclustertypeselection=ClassicMySQLReplication

# Indicates how is the InnoDB Cluster is/will be named.
# innodbclustername="sandboxCluster"

# Indicates how many instances will the InnoDB cluster sandbox will have.
# innodbclusterinstances=0

# Holds the InnoDB Cluster Username.
# innodbclusterusername

# Indicates the InnoDB Cluster URI.
# innodbclusteruri

# Indicates the InnoDB Cluster Port.
# innodbclusterport=3306

# Load mysql plugins at start."plugin_x ; plugin_y".
# plugin_load

# MySQL server's plugin configuration.
# loose_mysqlx_port=33060
```

You can find in this file (after I updated it!)

```
 [mysqld]
 lower_case_table_names=2
```

Then I tried (after restarting the server!)

```
mysql> create database AbcDeF;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| abcdef             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| rqatautomationdb   |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

After playing around, I got this

```
 The server option 'lower_case_table_names' is configured to use case sensitive table names but the data directory is on a case-insensitive file system which is an unsupported combination
```

I found this
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75185

I think it is not allowed to have case sensitive schema and table names on a case insensitive file system (NTFS).

Comment: Put that line under `# The MySQL server [mysqld]` section.Also you config file might be named my.ini rather than my.cnf

Comment: No, did not work.

Comment: Look here and try to find you file https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712684/1745672 assuming it`s not a xampp system

Comment: Thank, you! I did not know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes solution thanks to my collegue!

Use quotes **`` `SchemaName` ``** to create a schema name!

```
mysql> create database `Adatabase_name`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| Adatabase_name     |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Take a look at `Adatabase_name`. 
Note, I have `lower_case_table_names=2` in `my.ini` file. This is useful to find `my.ini` file. 
[I can not find my.cnf on my windows computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712646/i-can-not-find-my-cnf-on-my-windows-computer/1712684#1712684)

Answer (score 3):

Put it like this in your my.ini

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=2
```

Lines beginning with a `#` are a comment.

You can have several segments in the file. Under `[mysqld]` are options for the server, under `[mysql]` are options for the client, like the prompt for example.

Comment: This is what I found on these posts mentioned in my question. However, it did not work., But, let me try once more...

Comment: I agree, I needed this property in `my.ini` file. But this was not enough!