# docker build exception of type 'system.timeoutexception' was thrown

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

Am building a docker image of asp.net core 6 and am getting error when restoring packages, docker build exception of type 'system.timeoutexception' was thrown, I have updated wsl2 , reinstalled docker but still getting the same problem, my internet speed is 40mps

Comment: This question is already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928390/change-table-name-to-upper-case. Hope it Helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change table name to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928390/change-table-name-to-upper-case)

Answer (score 0):

Go to my.cnf file and add below line

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

Restart mysql server.
Try giving table names in upper case. It should work.